# Saving JSON data in SESSION to export excel

Tags: php, json, excel

I need to export data from a table in `.xlsx` format.

I want to know what is the best way to do it. Now, when the table is created I save this data in a SESSION to after create the file whit this data, so I want to do this more efficiently.

I dont know if saving data in json format helps... because.. the data frequently is so big.

Comment: does it have to be xlsx? csv is far more portable and compatible.

Comment: may be that would be a way.., but, How do you pass  or use the data of a query to print an html table and create the file later, I mean,  would you pass this data to session var ? or create another function to get the same data but creating the CSV or xlsx file, or other way

Comment: you don't need to save the data in SESSION either convert it to json for later export it to excel or csv. If you want excel, i recommend http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/